# Definition file not found error, is not part of the compilation output, angular 5

Tags: angular, npm, angular5

I'm working on an angular package with the following `package.json`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mds.angular.datetimepicker

```
{
  "name": "mds.angular.datetimepicker",
  "version": "2.0.5",
  "description": "Persian and gregorian DateTimePicker with angular and materials",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./index.js",
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "author": {
    "name": "Mohammad Dayyan",
    "url": "https://github.com/Mds92/mds-angular-datetime-picker-package"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "public",
    "url": "https://github.com/Mds92/mds-angular-datetime-picker-package"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Mds92/mds-angular-datetime-picker-package",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mds.persian.datetime": "^0.9.82",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  }
}
```

I created a definition file `index.ts` as following:

```
export * from "./mds-datetime-picker.module";
export * from "./services/mds-datetime-picker-resources.service";
export * from "./components/mds-datetime-picker.component";
export * from "./components/core/mds-datetime-picker-core.component";
export * from "./assests/mds-datetime-picker.utility";
export * from "./assests/enums";
export * from "./assests/interfaces";
```

`tsc -d` command runs successfully and `index.d.ts` created as follows:

```
export * from "./mds-datetime-picker.module";
export * from "./services/mds-datetime-picker-resources.service";
export * from "./components/mds-datetime-picker.component";
export * from "./components/core/mds-datetime-picker-core.component";
export * from "./assests/mds-datetime-picker.utility";
export * from "./assests/enums";
export * from "./assests/interfaces";
```

Problem:
When I install this package in another project (sample-project) with `npm i mds.angular.datetimepicker@latest` I get the following error in `ng build` command

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/mds.angular.datetimepicker/assests/enums.ts
Module build failed: Error: D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\mds.angular.datetimepicker\assests\enums.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:625:23)
    at plugin.done.then (D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
 @ ./node_modules/mds.angular.datetimepicker/index.js 11:9-35
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./node_modules/mds.angular.datetimepicker/assests/mds-datetime-picker.utility.ts
Module build failed: Error: D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\mds.angular.datetimepicker\assests\mds-datetime-picker.utility.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:625:23)
    at plugin.done.then (D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
 @ ./node_modules/mds.angular.datetimepicker/index.js 10:9-57
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./node_modules/mds.angular.datetimepicker/components/core/mds-datetime-picker-core.component.ts
Module build failed: Error: D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\mds.angular.datetimepicker\components\core\mds-datetime-picker-core.component.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:625:23)
    at plugin.done.then (D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
 @ ./node_modules/mds.angular.datetimepicker/index.js 9:9-72
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./node_modules/mds.angular.datetimepicker/components/mds-datetime-picker.component.ts
Module build failed: Error: D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\mds.angular.datetimepicker\components\mds-datetime-picker.component.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:625:23)
    at plugin.done.then (D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
 @ ./node_modules/mds.angular.datetimepicker/index.js 8:9-62
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./node_modules/mds.angular.datetimepicker/mds-datetime-picker.module.ts
Module build failed: Error: D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\mds.angular.datetimepicker\mds-datetime-picker.module.ts is not part of
the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:625:23)
    at plugin.done.then (D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
 @ ./node_modules/mds.angular.datetimepicker/index.js 6:9-48
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./node_modules/mds.angular.datetimepicker/services/mds-datetime-picker-resources.service.ts
Module build failed: Error: D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\mds.angular.datetimepicker\services\mds-datetime-picker-resources.service.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:625:23)
    at plugin.done.then (D:\Sources\Mds92.github.io\MdsDateTimePickerSample\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
 @ ./node_modules/mds.angular.datetimepicker/index.js 7:9-68
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

also I get the following error in `ng build --prod` command

```
ERROR in Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(28,117): Property 'templateType' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(33,125): Property 'templateType' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(43,115): Property 'textBoxType' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(48,123): Property 'textBoxType' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(58,113): Property 'inLine' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(63,105): Property 'inLine' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(73,119): Property 'isPersian' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(78,111): Property 'isPersian' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(88,123): Property 'persianChar' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(93,115): Property 'persianChar' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(103,121): Property 'timePicker' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(108,113): Property 'timePicker' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(118,127): Property 'rangeSelector' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(123,119): Property 'rangeSelector' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(132,73): Property 'format' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(138,73): Property 'placeHolder' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(144,73): Property 'buttonIcon' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(28,117): Property 'templateType' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(28,144): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(33,125): Property 'templateType' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(33,152): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(43,115): Property 'textBoxType' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(43,141): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(48,123): Property 'textBoxType' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(48,149): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(58,113): Property 'inLine' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(58,134): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(63,105): Property 'inLine' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(63,126): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(73,119): Property 'isPersian' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(73,143): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(78,111): Property 'isPersian' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(78,135): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(88,123): Property 'persianChar' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(88,149): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(93,115): Property 'persianChar' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(93,141): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(103,121): Property 'timePicker' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(103,146): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(108,113): Property 'timePicker' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(108,138): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(118,127): Property 'rangeSelector' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(118,155): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(123,119): Property 'rangeSelector' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(123,147): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(132,73): Property 'format' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(132,94): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(138,73): Property 'placeHolder' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(138,99): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(144,73): Property 'buttonIcon' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
Error at D:/Sources/Mds92.github.io/MdsDateTimePickerSample/src/app/app.component.html(144,98): Property 'settingChange' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.
```

My `package.json` in `sample-project`

```
{
  "name": "mds-date-time-picker-sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "mds.angular.datetimepicker": "^2.0.5",
    "mds.persian.datetime": "^0.9.82",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.53",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

`App.moodule.ts` in sample project:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MdsDatetimePickerModule } from 'mds.angular.datetimepicker';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, MdsDatetimePickerModule, FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`app.component.ts` of sample project

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

`app.component.html` is empty

My project was angular 4.4.2 and works well, after update to 5.0.3 the error occured